Why does Rust keep unreachable objects alive?
When some control paths would drop a value, all control paths after that point cannot access that variable again. In the following example, it would be an error to access the guard after the if statement. Despite this, Rust doesn't actually drop the value until it goes out of scope. Why not? I can't think of any legitimate reason to keep the object alive, and it seems likely to cause deadlocks (which is how I came across this behavior).
use scopeguard; // 1.2.0

fn func(guard: impl std::fmt::Debug) {
    if false {
        drop(guard);
    }
    println!("guard is not yet dropped")
}

fn main() {
    let guard = scopeguard::guard((), |_| println!("value dropped"));
    func(guard);
}

A related question, Why is this value not dropped after last use? is different because the value is still name-able after the last use. In this question, the value is un-name-able after the if statement (with exceptions shown in the accepted answer).

Out of interest, was this a production build or a dev build? I know in other languages lifetimes can be extended in case the developer might want to attach a debugger and inspect e.g. method arguments despite them otherwise being eligible for collection.

It's in release mode: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=7914ad040689157507399839ba13a451

Debug vs. release turns out to be irrelevant in this case. There is no ambiguity in the specification that would affect the outcome here.


I can't think of any legitimate reason to keep the object alive

Rust is obeying a consistent specification of semantics, in which dropping depends on going out of scope. While alternative semantics are possible, and could be the subject of future Rust editions, the exact rules of how to drop things early could add complexity and cause confusion. For example, a return statement would be an exception, because this code works:
fn func(guard: impl std::fmt::Debug) {
    if false {
        drop(guard);
        return;
    }
    println!("{guard:?} is not yet dropped") // ScopeGuard { value: () } is not yet dropped

}


it seems likely to cause deadlocks

If your code seems especially susceptible to deadlocks, it may benefit from refactoring. Otherwise, just move drop to after if or also drop in else.

Another option would be to move the guard into a scope that encloses the if: { let guard = guard; if false { drop(guard); } } println!(...);.
